# Debug assertion failed. C++ vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector

Hi Im trying to get my program to read in a line from a file, split it by space into a vector, and then act on that vector. When I run the program I get the above error, which Im guessing means im calling a vector slot that doesnt exist. The code in question is below, but Im having trouble figuring out the exact part of my error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
     while (getline(fin,temp))
{

    vector<string> token;
    split(token,temp,is_any_of(" "));
    // check and print the tokens to new file
    for (int i = 0; i < token.size(); i++)
    {
        string uni = token[i];
        string bi = token[i]+" "+token[i+1];
        string tri = token[i]+" "+token[i+1]+" "+token[i+2];
        if(Filter.check(tri)==true)
        {
            token[i],token[i+1],token[i+2]==censor;
            outputFile<<token[i]<<" "<<token[i+1]<<" "<<token[i+2];
            i+3;
        }
        else if(Filter.check(bi)==true)
        {
            token[i],token[i+1]==censor;
            outputFile<<token[i]<<" "<<token[i+1];
            i+2;
        }
        else if(Filter.check(uni)==true)
        {
            token[i]==censor;
            outputFile<<token[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
            outputFile<<token[i];
    }
    outputFile<<endl;

}
```

To help understand what Im doing, the program should check the lines for specific words or phrases, replace them with a censor, and output those words to a file.

EDIT: Ok so Ive changed the for loop to look like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < token.size()-2; i++)
```

But I am still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @0x1337: If it were empty, the loop would not run at all.

Comment: What should this line do: `token[i],token[i+1],token[i+2]==censor;`?

Comment: Censor is a string = "****" and I just realized that should be =censor not ==, though thats not related to the problem.

Comment: @CoreyHall `token[i]==censor;`  What are you attempting to accomplish with this line of code, and similar lines that look like this (with the `==`)?

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
string bi = token[i]+" "+token[i+1];
```

accesses the element which is one past the length of the array when `i` is `token.size()-1`. Similarly, this line

```
string tri = token[i]+" "+token[i+1]+" "+token[i+2];
```

goes two elements past the end.

Change the loop to stop at `token.size()-3` to fix this problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < token.size()-2; i++)
    ...
```

or add checks inside the loop to see if `i` is small enough to grab one or two elements after it.

Comment: I see what you mean. I changed the for to stop early like you said but I am still getting the error message.

Comment: @CoreyHall If this is Visual Studio you should be able to see what line of your code is causing the subscript out of range by walking up the callstack after the assertion.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes it is, but when I click Retry to debug, it notifies me that the program has crashed.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you use statements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < token.size(); i++)

string bi = token[i]+" "+token[i+1];
string tri = token[i]+" "+token[i+1]+" "+token[i+2];
```

What will happen for `i = token.size() - 1` ?
You will try to read

```
token[token.size() - 1] + " " + toke[token.size()] + token[token.size()+1]
```

Last two values are out of the vector range

Comment: I edited the for to stop early but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers gave you an indication of the error.  However, your code is still broken, even if you attempt to stop the loop from going over the edge.

If there are 2 or less tokens, this will cause a debug assertion (in Visual Studio)

```
 string bi = token[i]+" "+token[i+1];   // <-- debug assertion if only 1 token
 string tri = token[i]+" "+token[i+1]+" "+token[i+2];  // <-- assertion if only 2 tokens
```

When you first enter the loop, you are trying to grab the second token, but if there is only 1 token, there is no second token.

Similarly, if there are only 2 tokens, the second line on the initial entry of the loop tries to grab the third token, but there is no third token.

So what you should be doing is ensuring that there are 3 or more tokens *before* you enter the loop.

```
if (token.size() < 3 )
   return;
for (int i = 0; i < token.size(); i++)
```

Either that, or rewrite your loop to handle 1 or 2 tokens.